# Updating UI Elements from Data in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am building an iOS app to be a user interface (HMI) for a machine; the machine is controlled by a PC (windowsCE).

Data can only be read from the PC via sockets. The PC has a structure of data which contains various data types, bool/int/string etc. The data in this structure can be constantly changing, although the length and order of data types in this structure does not change.
The fastest way we've found for the PC to send data is for it to send ALL data in the structure in one string. The data is represented by hex-coded pairs.
I know before receiving the data what order the data is in and the data types
I need to display this data on buttons and labels (UI Elements)

This is our current way of updating the UI Elements states:

1. The data is read from the socket into an array, RawDataArray, periodically every 0.1 seconds.
2. Each UI Element knows where its data is in the RawDataArray and its data type.
3. With another timer, the UI Element can check its data and update accordingly.

The question is really one of program architecture. Is there a better, more appropriate or more elegant way for a UI element to update its state rather than blindly polling a position in an array to see if its data has changed? Should I be somehow using CoreData?

Comment: CoreData is for object persistence, so I don't see a use for it in what you've described.  Rather than having UI elements interpret data, I think it would be more "normal" for a view controller to do the parsing and then supply processed values to the actual UI.

Comment: If you've got code that breaks the RawDataArray into distinct properties you could look at using Key-Value Observers https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html